# Does Textmate have the Xcode like "back gestures"?

Tags: xcode, textmate

I find that the xcode back gestures is very useful. It allows me to jump back the last position I edit, is there similar features in Textmate too?

Answer (score 0):

No, TextMate doesn't have the same "back" behavior that Xcode does. It does have "bookmarks" that you can set to mark interesting places in the text, and you can cycle through the bookmarks in either direction. Bookmarks can be used like Xcode's "back" feature except that you have to explicitly mark the spot to which you want to return.